# Problems with common legend in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to combine legends of a series of 22 plots but I simply can't make it work.

My legend represents months and each plot is different, some have info in just some of the months.

So the final legend is showing only the legend of my first plot (that only has data in 2 months), and I have no other plot with data in all the months to be used for the legend to be complete.

Any way to fix this?

Trying this:
ggarrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, 
          p13, p14, p15, p16, p17, p18, p19, p20, p21, p22, 
          ncol=6, nrow=4, common.legend = TRUE, legend="bottom")

https://oregonstate.box.com/s/gxgo93mpva9wdx9lcfem26cer8ixpcs8

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by including sample data and code. Avoid using images of data or code. Use `dput` for data.

Answer (score 0):

for a better understanding of the obstacles, it is interesting that you provide some reproducible example, but by your text I think it is possible to understand the basics of your problem.

Recently I saw something similar, and managed to solve in a not so elegant way.

1. Perform the organization of all your plots without legend.

From `p1` to`p22` with `show.legend = FALSE` for each 'row' (`nrow`) of your plot set. Then transform into `grob`.

```
library(cowplot)
obj1 <- cowplot::plot_grid(p1,  ..., p6,  align = "hv", nrow = 1)
obj2 <- cowplot::plot_grid(p7,  ..., p12, align = "hv", nrow = 1)
obj3 <- cowplot::plot_grid(p13, ..., p18, align = "hv", nrow = 1)
obj4 <- cowplot::plot_grid(p19, ..., p22, NULL, NULL, align = "hv", nrow = 1)

g1grob <- ggplot2::ggplotGrob(obj1)
g2grob <- ggplot2::ggplotGrob(obj2)
g3grob <- ggplot2::ggplotGrob(obj3)
g4grob <- ggplot2::ggplotGrob(obj4)
```

You can continue to use `ggarrange`, but not necessarily mind you need to share the legend. I suggest observing the `plot_grid` function of the `cowplot` package, using the `align = "hv"` argument ([link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html)).

2. You need to create an object (`objx`) so that it has the most complex caption possible, addressing all your points of interest. For from this object you should get its caption using the `cowplot` package with the `get_legend` ([link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/shared_legends.html)) function.

```
objx <- ggplot2::ggplot(df) + 
                 ... +
              theme(legend.position = "bottom")

legend <- cowplot::get_legend(objx)
```

3. Once this is done, it is only necessary to unite the objects of interest, the plot (`obj`) and the legend (`legend`).

```
lay <- rbind(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
             c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
             c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
             c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4))
plot_leila <- gridExtra::grid.arrange(g1grob, g2grob, g3grob, g4grob,
                                      layout_matrix = lay)

lay <- rbind(c(rep(1,12)),
             c(2))
plot_leila <- gridExtra::grid.arrange(plot_leila, legend,
                                      layout_matrix = lay)
plot_leila
```

---

> Eventual misalignments can occur, but with patience and testing the packages you will surely get a good result.